# SCSS dynamic selectors

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this SCSS code:

```
$box-length: 12 !default;
@for $i from 1 through $box-length {
  .box-#{$i} {
    flex: 0 0 (100% / $box-length * $i);
  }
}
```

Below, I need to add the generated `.box-{num}` classes with other selectors.
To have a CSS result like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row,
  .column,
  .box,
  .box-1,
  .box-2,
  .box-3,
  .box-4,
  .box-5 {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

How to append the dynamic `.box-{num}` classes to `.row, .column, .box`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Using a [placeholder selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#placeholder-selectors) and [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    %mq-768 {
        /* ... */
    }
}

.row,
.column,
.box {
  @extend %mq-768;
}

$box-length: 12 !default;
@for $i from 1 through $box-length {
  .box-#{$i} {
    @extend %mq-768;
    flex: 0 0 (100% / $box-length * $i);
  }
}
```

Compiles as:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .box-12,
  .box-11,
  [...],
  .box-2,
  .box-1,
  .row,
  .column,
  .box {
    /* ... */
  }
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 0 0 8.3333333333%;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 0 0 16.6666666667%;
}

[...]

.box-12 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

#### 2. Using a variable to store the selectors and [`append`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list#append):

```
$selectors: ".row, .column, .box";

$box-length: 12 !default;
@for $i from 1 through $box-length {
    $boxSelector: ".box-#{$i}" ;
    $selectors: append($selectors, $boxSelector, $separator: comma);
    
  #{$boxSelector} {
    flex: 0 0 (100% / $box-length * $i);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #{$selectors} {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Compiles as:

```
.box-1 {
  flex: 0 0 8.3333333333%;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 0 0 16.6666666667%;
}

[...]

.box-12 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row,
  .column,
  .box,
  .box-1,
  .box-2,
  [...],
  .box-11,
  .box-12 {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```